# Asking the user if they want to play again

Tags: python, loops, random

Basically it's a guessing game and I have literally all the code except for the last part where it asks if the user wants to play again. how do I code that, I use a while loop correct?

heres my code:

```
import random
number=random.randint(1,1000)
count=1
guess= eval(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 1000 "))

while guess !=number:
count+=1

 if guess > number + 10:
  print("Too high!")
 elif guess < number - 10:
  print("Too low!")
 elif guess > number:
  print("Getting warm but still high!")
 elif guess < number:
  print("Getting warm but still Low!")

 guess = eval(input("Try again "))
print("You rock! You guessed the number in" , count , "tries!")

while guess == number:
 count=1
 again=str(input("Do you want to play again, type yes or no "))
if again == yes:
```

guess= eval(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 1000 "))

```
if again == no:
break
```

Comment: Never do `eval(input(...))`.  It is a massive security hole because it can execute arbitrary Python code.  Use `int(input(...))` instead to make the inputs into numbers.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Your code is nonsense is if it is not properly indented.

Comment: Elaborating iCodez's comment: [eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: meh to be fair if eval is only bad when taking user input on a machine other than the person providing input... its pretty hard to accidentally put bad code into input ... if the user inputs `format /F /S C:` then they are being malicious ... and they will brick their own computer... (all that said by and large avoid `eval`)

Answer (score 1):

One big while loop around the whole program

```
import random

play = True

while play:
  number=random.randint(1,1000)
  count=1
  guess= eval(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 1000 "))

    while guess !=number:
      count+=1

      if guess > number + 10:
        print("Too high!")
      elif guess < number - 10:
        print("Too low!")
      elif guess > number:
        print("Getting warm but still high!")
      elif guess < number:
        print("Getting warm but still Low!")

      guess = eval(input("Try again "))
    print("You rock! You guessed the number in" , count , "tries!")

    count=1
    again=str(input("Do you want to play again, type yes or no "))
    if again == "no":
      play = False
```

Comment: I think you meant `== "no"` and `play=False`...+1 for the minimal deviation from his code however (since false/true/no are non existant keywords... but most people will know what you meant)

Comment: whoops... copy-pasted from his code...

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `eval` (as @iCodex said) - it's risky, use `int(x)`. A way to do this is to use functions:

```
import random
import sys

def guessNumber():
    number=random.randint(1,1000)
    count=1
    guess= int(input("Enter your guess between 1 and 1000: "))

    while guess !=number:
        count+=1
        if guess > (number + 10):
            print("Too high!")
        elif guess < (number - 10):
            print("Too low!")
        elif guess > number:
            print("Getting warm but still high!")
        elif guess < number:
            print("Getting warm but still Low!")

        guess = int(input("Try again "))

    if guess == number:
        print("You rock! You guessed the number in ", count, " tries!")
        return

guessNumber()

again = str(input("Do you want to play again (type yes or no): "))
if again == "yes":
    guessNumber()
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Using functions mean that you can reuse the same piece of code as many times as you want.

Here, you put the code for the guessing part in a function called `guessNumber()`, call the function, and at the end, ask the user to go again, if they want to, they go to the function again.

Comment: I think you mean `if again == 'yes'`.

Comment: `again == yes` will probably give you a nameerror ...

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus yep, sorry!

Comment: on the line where it says while guess == number.... it's saying guess isn't defined. why is that? @ṧнʊß

Comment: @DesiBoy Are all the indents correct?

Comment: Yes I believe they are. It says NameError: name 'guess' is not defined

Comment: Okay i fixed it, but when I run the program it says "Do you want to play again" not "Enter a number between 1 and 1000

Comment: @DesiBoy See my edit (I forgot to call the function - sorry :)

Comment: Haha yea I saw that, but that was not the issue. It's saying guessNumber is not defined.

Comment: @DesiBoy try the edited code - you shuoldn't need that last while loop

Comment: yea I did the last edited code and it asks for random numbers, but when I enter the a number, the code just stops. try your code if you want, you will see what I mean. but I'll try to figure it out on my own, thanks!!

Comment: @DesiBoy See my edit - I've tested it, it works now :). Before, we'd said to just keep on incrementing the variable `guess`, but now, I've put the rest of the code in the first `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

separate your logic into functions

```
def get_integer_input(prompt="Guess A Number:"):
    while True:
       try: return int(input(prompt))
       except ValueError:
          print("Invalid Input... Try again")
```

for example to get your integer input and for your main game

```
import itertools
def GuessUntilCorrect(correct_value):
   for i in itertools.count(1):
       guess = get_integer_input()
       if guess == correct_value: return i
       getting_close = abs(guess-correct_value)<10
       if guess < correct_value:
          print ("Too Low" if not getting_close else "A Little Too Low... but getting close")
       else:
          print ("Too High" if not getting_close else "A little too high... but getting close")
```

then you can play like

```
tries = GuessUntilCorrect(27) 
print("It Took %d Tries For the right answer!"%tries)
```

you can put it in a loop to run forever

```
while True:
     tries = GuessUntilCorrect(27) #probably want to use a random number here
     print("It Took %d Tries For the right answer!"%tries)
     play_again = input("Play Again?").lower()
     if play_again[0] != "y":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to modify this program so that it can ask the user whether or not they want to input another number and if they answer 'no' the program terminates and vice versa. This is my code:

```
step=int(input('enter skip factor: '))
num = int(input('Enter a number: '))

while True:
  for i in range(0,num,step):    

    if (i % 2) == 0: 
       print( i, ' is Even')
    else:
       print(i, ' is Odd')
again = str(input('do you want to use another number? type yes or no')
        if again = 'no' :     
            break
```