# Loop to ask user to go again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple program that runs a game of Craps. All of the logic of the craps game is in the playOnce() method. I need to use a main() method that calls the playOnce() method in order to determine whether a user wants to play again by entering either yes or no. I need to constantly ask the user if they want to play after each round. I'm having trouble implementing that piece of the logic of asking the user. I have tried using a while loop, but so far no output. Here's a sample: http://tinypic.com/r/2las1v/8

### ----------------------------------------------------

```
import random

def playOnce():

   dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
   dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
   roll = dice1 + dice2
   print("You rolled", dice1, "+", dice2, "=", roll)
   print()
   if roll == 2 or roll == 3 or roll == 12:
       print("You lose!")
   elif roll == 7 or roll == 11:
       print("You win!")
   else:
       print("Point is", roll)
       dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
       dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
       roll2 = dice1 + dice2
       print("You rolled ",roll2)
   while roll2 != 7:
       if roll == roll2:
           print("You win!")
           break
       else:
           print("Point is ", roll)

       dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
       dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
       roll2 = dice1 + dice2
       print("You rolled ",roll2)

   if roll2 == 7:
       print("You lose!")

def main():
    playOnce()
    print("Would you like to go again?")

main()
```

Comment: It would be good if you could let us know what exactly you're having problems with? I.e. what have you tried already, and how does it fail?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961427/asking-the-user-if-they-want-to-play-again?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def main():
    keep_playing = True
    while keep_playing:
        playOnce()
        ans = raw_input("Would you like to go again?")
        if ans != 'y':
            keep_playing = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import random

def playOnce():

   dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
   dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
   roll = dice1 + dice2
   print("You rolled", dice1, "+", dice2, "=", roll)
   print()
   if roll == 2 or roll == 3 or roll == 12:
       print("You lose!")
   elif roll == 7 or roll == 11:
       print("You win!")
   else:
       print("Point is", roll)
       dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
       dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
       roll2 = dice1 + dice2
       print("You rolled ",roll2)
   while roll2 != 7:
       if roll == roll2:
           print("You win!")
           break
       else:
           print("Point is ", roll)

       dice1 = random.randint(1, 6)
       dice2 = random.randint(1, 6)
       roll2 = dice1 + dice2
       print("You rolled ",roll2)

   if roll2 == 7:
       print("You lose!")

def main():
    playOnce()
    #print("Would you like to go again?")
    flag = input("Would you like to go again?")
    #flag = True
    while flag:
        playOnce()
        flag = input("Would you like to go again?")

main()
```

Then you need reply True or False or 1 or 0